# Can I Ldap Sync replication to a different backend?

Tags: ldap, openldap, replication

My current OpenLDAP backend is BDB can I replicate (syncrepl) this to another server using a MDB backend?

Probably a no but thought I'd ask.

Thanks,
Andy